# Import multiple tabs from a ODS file using R while specifying exact ranges in each tab

Tags: r, ods

I'm trying to use the library readODS to import a file ('sample data.ods') with 30 tabs. 
Each tab has the exact same layout and I need to extract the exact same columns from each tab then combine them into 1 DF but I'm finding it difficult to do so. For example, I need to extract rows 5 to 20, with columns 3,5,7,9,11. An example of what I imagine it to look like is below (obviously, this is incorrect!)

```
my_df <- read_ods('pedestrianfootfall2013.ods', 
              sheet = 1:30, c[3,5,7,9,11], 
              rows(5:20))
```

And then I'm not sure whether I would use rbind or merge...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around...save the file as an Excel file and use the following:

```
library(plyr)
library(XLConnect)


df1 <- loadWorkbook('filename.xlsx')
df1_sheets <- getSheets(df1)



for (ws in df1_sheets) {
  df2 <- readWorksheet(df1, sheet = 1:52, header=TRUE, startRow = 230, endRow = 254)
}


df2_all <- ldply(df2, rbind)
df2_Reduced <- df2_all[c(1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14)]
```